# GSON fromJson returns null

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm looking to parse JSONobjects, but I keep getting null when using fromJson. I'm sure inputStream is valid, it looks like the reader is initialized and filled as well, but  'response' keeps coming back null, causing an fatal exception. I am expecting to get a 'response' with 3 fields, one of which a result type list, with the only field in result being the name. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the following code:

```
    String url = uribuilder.build().toString();

    try {
        HttpRequest httpRequest = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(url));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpRequest.execute();
        inputStream = httpResponse.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
    List<Result> resultList = response.results;
```

SearchResponse class:

```
package com.example.places;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.util.List;

    public class SearchResponse {

        @SerializedName("html_attributions")
        public String html_attributions;

        public List<Result> results;

        @SerializedName("status")
        public String status;

    }
```

Result class:

```
package com.example.places;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

    public class Result {

        @SerializedName("name")
        public String name;

    }
```

This is an example of the JSON inputStream, which I have confirmed is being downloaded in the var inputStream.

```
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [
    {
    "geometry" : {
    "location" : {
    "lat" : 52.3784713,
    "lng" : 4.629422400000001
    }
    },
    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
    "id" : "426ed4299daa6451e2293b1677e06b524562c547",
    "name" : "Lange Lakenstraat",
    "reference" : "CqQBoAAAANEj46iTeMbRHeUcEGFeaCAMrnHxXvFpadEefjrl4qDBitY4b5c2kjVunQrm496UeU1BHLiflo4tA6z7sDBZw3u0b2oPwTqOSiA1Jf4TZA3J6GeGfo_0tLV5dnHH2a3gJbl7fnDvWdZco2BvP_mgVSJgcC2hnb3H8xf9_HYUKtWjAPiV-lY-TnIeZqJaAaH7rJfg9OuHMjmYVYnYuaW0FoQSEEBP1JORpML1X0D9qgGPl0QaFJhSaAVENN_I4-p8tK-5B790QkwD",
    "types" : [ "route" ],
    "vicinity" : "Oude Stad"
    },
    {
    "geometry" : {
    "location" : {
    "lat" : 52.3812134,
    "lng" : 4.633607599999999
    },
    "viewport" : {
    "northeast" : {
    "lat" : 52.3854271,
    "lng" : 4.644829
    },
    "southwest" : {
    "lat" : 52.375918,
    "lng" : 4.624482899999999
    }
    }
    },
    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
    "id" : "7b7289c46ec49e2de4c7922bb1489f4b7d285385",
    "name" : "Centrum",
    "reference" : "CpQBjQAAAPTn0HELVmsIds40sY_RGXIY1GmrhqlfejMmrQrG2Gl095VujXOugcPR5ZuZ3-aNZhLZEXNsOO_Ghf_0vEnIkjVan11tb1WtDiwJrIfAa31hPt8XlIGY3JBWKXew0qVpGXZbEoHvhThzn-z0OBZ0pqMR5PZrU7mgoH26pbAR_y-Nngo74sQHZs9wO3dzQl34RRIQMvDj3KMrzUBgSf6WVVHzNRoUlDtZh_8FsLn3qaEWzvPnnyFe9j8",
    "types" : [ "sublocality", "political" ],
    "vicinity" : "Centrum"
    }
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
    }
```

Comment: On Search response it should be List<Result> results; or ArrayList<Result> results;

Comment: Do you mean "List<Result> results = response.results;"? If so, that makes no difference unfortunately. I'm not sure how to use List<Result> results; in the SearchResponse line.

Comment: Sorry, I put it wrong. I mean on your SearchResponse class.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately I still get a null though. I updated the code above.

Comment: Try with this code:

source = new BufferedInputStream((inputStream));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
SearchResponse response = gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);

Comment: No luck. the BufferedInputStream does fill, but SearchResponse still returns null.

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask? Did you paused your  code on this line:
List<Result> resultList = response.results;
and there is the response object null???

Comment: Yes for both. Async task, and a break on that line. That line causes the fatal exception (null reference), but the search response is already null there.

Comment: I can't be sure, but you should check the return value of your AsyncTask. You should have:
return gson.fromJson(reader, SearchResponse.class);
in your doInBackground method, and do:
List<Result> resultList = result.results; 
in the onPostExecute method. 
Maybe the exception could be related with that.

Comment: I found the error. Why it was a nullpointer and not a IllegalStat exception, I don't know, but I got it working (see the answer). Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, strange one. In this case the error came from the SearchResponse class. If you look at the JSON, the first field is

```
"html_attributions" : [],
```

So an array.

in SearchResponse

```
public String html_attributions;
```

should be

```
public String[] html_attributions;
```

The code now shows signs of life. Why it threw a null exception instead of a to be expected "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY ", I have no idea.

Comment: If anybody's encountering this, I got this when converting {"request_id":"a091f9c12e6e431ab3878e1359f0aa21","status":"0"} to a Java class with status as String, and it only happened when I published it in the Google Play store. I changed it to int and it was fixed. Stranger and hard to debug..

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, but in my case I had this object:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeDto {
    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Crew Id")
    private String crewId;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Employee Role")
    private String employeeRole;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Employee First Name")
    private String firstName;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Employee Last Name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

And this was the string from a previous query:

```
{"crewId":"924142","employeeRole":"Manager","firstName":"Hans","lastName":"Miller"}
```

The problem was because of camelCase notation, so I changed it to:

```
{"crew_id":"924142","employee_role":"Manager","first_name":"Hans","last_name":"Miller"}
```

According with the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) that field policy can be defined in Gson:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
```